# using magentos server-side validation

Tags: validation, magento

I am using Magento version 1.7.0.2 and have created a custom module, in which there is a form that allows user to pass information in to the database.

I need to validate user input and looking around Google all i can see is front-end validation tutorials, I assume magento has server side validation tools? Based on this assumption I had a look in mage/core/customer/block/form/register.php and mage/core/customer/helper/data.php but have been unable to find anything of help, am i looking in the wrong place?

I am aware Zend has some validation, and will use that if Magento has not got it's own/extended zend validation.

In short, does Magento have it's own validation apart from the javascript validation tools?

Answer (score 0):

Magento uses Zend for validation, you can take a look inside Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php at the method validate()

Comment: It is not a valid path.

Comment: @alumi The path should be ok now.